# Developer Console Execute Anonymous not updating Query

Tags: apex, query, update

I have the following query that is supposed to find all the entered data (Contact List) within the range of 2017 and 2016 ( which for some reason returning 2015 back) and see if the Firstname is empty copy the last name and enter it there. but every time I run this inside the

Developer Console -> Debug -> Open Execute Anonymous Window , it stops and gives me error, and says the required field is missing

> "Line: 8, Column: 1 System.DmlException: Update failed. First
>   exception on row 82 with id 0031600002B3oy7AAB; first error:
>   FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, First name MUST be entered: []"

```
for(List<Contact> conList :[SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName,Contact_type__c, Commission_Spiff__c FROM Contact Contact WHERE ( CreatedDate < 2017-03-09T14:19:25.000Z   OR CreatedDate > 2016-12-01T14:19:25.000Z)])
 {
  for(Contact ob: conList)
   {        
   if(ob.FirstName == NULL){
      ob.FirstName = ob.LastName; 

   }             

}
  update conList;
}
```

Contact Validation Rule

Error Condition Formula
ISBLANK(FirstName)
Error Message
First name MUST be entered

Comment: Could you specify the validation rule which you have on Contact Firstname field ?

Comment: @Lakshman hi, yes I just updated the question but basically in contact object I have ISBLANK(FirstName)

Comment: NULL and EmptyString are two different things. I think the solution posted below should help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you also need to check the length of FirstName

```
for(List<Contact> conList :[SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName,Contact_type__c, Commission_Spiff__c 
FROM Contact Contact 
WHERE ( CreatedDate < 2017-03-09T14:19:25.000Z   AND CreatedDate > 2016-12-01T14:19:25.000Z)])
     {
      for(Contact ob: conList)
       {        
       if(ob.FirstName == NULL || ob.FirstName.trim().length()==0){
          ob.FirstName = ob.LastName; 
       } 
    }
      update conList;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Two issues here:

1. Your query is returning 2015 results because your WHERE condition is satisfied by any record created before March 9 2017 **OR** after Dec 1 2016. 2015 is before 2017, so the first condition is met. To fix this, just change OR to AND so it only returns records meeting *both* criteria.
2. You are likely running up against the validation rule because the conditional inside your for loop only fixes records where first name is NULL, which is *not the same thing as blank*. You can use the **[isBlank String method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_isBlank)** to check for null and blank at the same time.